# How do I test helpers in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

With this `ApplicationHelper`:

```
class ApplicationHelper 
  def my_method
    link_to 'foo', 'bar'
  end  
end
```

and this `application_helper_spec`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe 'links' do 
    it 'should call a helper method' do
      expect(helper.my_method).to eq("<a href='bar'>foo</a>")
    end
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble getting things to work as as I expected from the [latest documentation I can find on Rails helper specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec). (The docs are for Ruby 3 and I'm using 4.) There doesn't appear to be a `helper` object:

```
undefined local variable or method `helper' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationHelper::Links:0x007fda1895c2f8>
```

If instead I do this:

```
require 'rails_helper'
include ApplicationHelper

describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe 'links' do 
    it 'should call a helper method' do
      expect(my_method).to eq("<a href='bar'>foo</a>")
    end
  end
end
```

now `my_method` is called correctly but `link_to` is not defined:

```
undefined method `link_to' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationHelper::Links:0x007fda1c4c3e90>
```

(This latter case is the same as if I define `config.include ApplicationHelper` in `rails_helper`.)

Obviously the spec environment does not include all the standard Rails helpers. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you requiring spec helper that loads Rails environment in rails_helper?

Comment: you should take a look at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec

Comment: Can you push your project on github I am quite sure you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to either enable the `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` option, or explicitly set the test type, e.g.:

`describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
  ...
end`

Comment: Thank you @Andy -- `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` seems to be what I was missing here (in `rails_helper`).

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Andy Waite's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37908215/567863) regarding defining `type: :helper` on your spec is correct in that it will solve your `undefined local variable or method 'helper'` issues.

However, as for the overarching question of "How do I test helpers in Rails 4?", and specifically your method that seems to just make a call to [`ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper#link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), assuming that you don't want to cover this in a feature spec and want to test it in isolation, consider that if you want to test that "calling `#my_method` returns a string containing HTML for a foo bar link", [the `link_to` tests for `UrlHelper` itself](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionview/test/template/url_helper_test.rb) would confirm that calling `link_to 'foo', 'bar'` will return `"<a href='bar'>foo</a>"`.

So, I'd suggest moving your specs up one level higher, saying that you want to test that "calling `#my_method` returns me a link for foo bar (in whatever way Rails hands me back links)":

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
  describe '#my_method' do
    it 'returns a foo bar link' do
      expect(helper).to receive(:link_to).with('foo', 'bar')
      helper.my_method
    end
  end
end
```

Personally though, I don't think this method has enough logic in it to warrant testing in isolation in a helper spec, and you'd be better off covering it in a feature spec where I assume you'd be testing for the display of the link, or clicking it to see what happens etc.

Comment: Thank you @Paul -- I should have clarified that my question was just a stripped-down example. The actual method in question here has a bit more logic to it, enough to deserve an actual test.